# Bold text using JQUERY: Traversing and changing the font

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working on customizing a page, and want to change a specific field's text to render as bold. When I inspect the field with chrome it has

```
<span id="_Datacomp_name" class="VIEWBOX" style="WIDTH:&quot;100px&quot;">testCompany</span>
```

How can I use JQUERY to select this field and then make it bold?

I understand HTML, but am new to JQUERY.

I thought using this would work:

```
<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/.../jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#_Datacomp_name").AwesomeBoldFunctionHere;
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you not doing this with CSS?

Comment: try $(document).ready(function(){ $("#_Datacomp_name").css('font-weight', 'bold');

Comment: Because the CSS doesn't have a class just for that field.

Comment: I've tried the methods suggested, don't know if it matters but it's an ASP page, and it's not registering anything suggested so far, I'll keep at it and update when I find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('#_Datacomp_name').css('fontWeight', 'bold');
});
```

<kbd>[**Documentation: jQuery.css**](http://api.jquery.com/css/)</kbd> <kbd>[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zjd2b/)</kbd>

And... If you're wondering about the `$(function() { })` syntax <kbd>[**jQuery.ready**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)</kbd>:

All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:

- `$( document ).ready( handler )`
- `$().ready( handler ) (this is not recommended)`
- `$( handler )`

Being the `handler` your `function() { }`

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help. Kept my friday from lasting into saturday mate!

Answer (score 2):

Try [this](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
$("#_Datacomp_name").css("font-weight", "bold");
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can do this,
    `document.getElementById("_Datacomp_name").style.fontweight = "bold";`

In JQuery,
   `$("#_Datacomp_name").css("font-weight", "bold");`

In CSS,
    `#_Datacomp_name {
    font-weight:bold;
    }`